# NgFor with variable keys?

Tags: angular, typescript

*'Headers' (headers: any;) are keys extracted from'data.items[0]' using 'object.keys'.*

How should i loop through 'data.items' objects. It doesn't work if i try to loop though with *ngfor

this is the result i want.
[image]

But i am getting error when i use 'item.header',

> Property 'header' does not exist on type '{ name: string; alias:
> string[]; qty: number; price: number; total: number; }

if i try 'item[header]'

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ name: string; alias: string[]; qty: number; price: number; total: number; }

**CODE**

**Object**

```js
  private itemData: sale = {
    type: '',
    data: { date: ' ', InvoiceNo: ' ', tax: ' ' },
    total: { semitotal: 0, grandtotal: 0 },
    items: [
      { name: 'item 1', alias: ['01a'], qty: 0, price: 0, total: 0 },
      { name: 'item 2', alias: ['02a'], qty: 5, price: 250, total: 0 },
      { name: 'item 3', alias: ['03a'], qty: 6, price: 350, total: 0 },
      { name: 'item 4', alias: ['04a'], qty: 1, price: 150, total: 0 },
    ],
    params: {},
  };
```

**Angular HTML Code**

```
 <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of itemData.items" class="table-data" >
            <td *ngFor="let header of headers"> 
                <input  type="text" [value]="item.header">  <---------- Problem 
            </td>
        </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Comment: can you please clarify from where the 'headers' is suppose to come to line this - '<td *ngFor="let header of headers"> ' ??

Comment: Headers is just keys array extracted from  itemData.items[0]----->
headers = Object.keys(this.data.items[0])
Now i am trying to use same keys to access values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `type` for the keys of an individual item and use that to index on an individual item:

```js
type SaleTableHeader = "name" | "qty" | "alias" | "price" | "total";

// Component class
headers: SaleTableHeader[] = Object.keys(this.itemData.items[0]) as SaleTableHeader[];

// Component Template
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of itemData.items" class="table-data">
    <td *ngFor="let header of headers">
      <input type="text" [value]="item[header]" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do this:

**html**

```
<tbody>
    <table class="table">
    <th *ngFor="let header of itemData.items[0] | keyvalue" class="table-data"> 
        {{header.key}}
    </th>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of itemData.items" class="table-data" >
       <td *ngFor="let r of item | keyvalue">
        <input type="text"[value]="r.value">
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</tbody>
```

**Output**
[image]